# Unity : Handling unregistration of a custom EventHandler with UnityEvent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have used a custom (system) EventHandler I created:

```
public event EventHandler<T> OnItemSelected;
```

I am then assigning a custom anonymous function:

```
.OnItemSelected += (...) => {};
```

However I am pretty sure that it isn't cleaning itself and when my `gameObject` is destroyed this causes a memory leak.
How can I prevent this ? Should I replace my `EventHandler` by a `UnityEvent` and use `RemoveAllListeners` ?

Comment: Some say it's appropriate to register events in Unity MonoBehavior's `OnEnable()` and to unregister them in `OnDisable()` (via `-=`), but maybe someone else knows a better pattern for you.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't!**

Lambda expressions are as you say anonymous and therefore can not be unregistered since you can not address them!

If you need to remove them later - **don't** use lambdas but rather explicit methods like e.g. instead of

```
OnItemSelected += (T) => { ... };
```

rather explicitly use

```
private void HandleItemSelected(T value)
{
    ...
}

OnItemSelected += HandleItemSelected;
```

which now you can also remove using

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
    OnItemSelected -= HandleItemSelected;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am here to discuss how Unity can help me with this issue, not how to do in c#.

Comment: @Scipion but ... Unity is based on c# and all your scripts will probably be c# .. so this is basically a question about c#. Which tool you want to use depends on you. I showed how you can remove the listener from the `EventHandler`. If you rather want to use `UnityEvent` there speaks nothing against it really.